# Is this question okay or is it redundant?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions, exact-duplicates

Alright. So right now I'm reading Peyton Quinn's novels. Are there any other important novels I need to read? I want to get to know the common ones people read. I mean what are the top ten that people usually read?

Answer (score 3):

I think the way you've currently worded the question is not really suitable.

One of the defining things about the Stack Exchange sites is that they are Q&A focused rather than discussion oriented. This means we like to avoid questions that are likely to produce unverifiable opinion or extended discussion.

However, some of the SE sites are a bit looser with this definition, and we do allow a little bit of slack on this site. But rather than asking for the top 10 list, I think you would be better off asking questions like:

> What is Peyton Quinn's definitive book?

This narrows the question to just one or two books, and it becomes a whole lot easier to quantify why those specific books are "the best" from his range. As an author he is likely to have a couple of really good books, and a bunch of space-fillers that are not so good.

Or another suggestion is to keep it to specific techniques or contents from the books:

> Peyton Quinn suggests *xyz* in book #1, but then suggests *abc* in book #2. What is the difference between the two approaches?

Keep in mind that while I'm answering as a moderator, ultimately it is the community that decides whether a question is on topic or not. So even if you phrase a question as I suggested there is no guarantee that it won't still attract close votes or down votes. To help avoid that, keep the question focused and well written - quality is king.